# Can anyone explain me this Object.keys(this_obj).forEach((key)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

can anyone explain to me about this code snippet and is there any simple way to write it.

```
Object.keys(this_obj).forEach((key) => {
        if (key === 'string') {
            result.push(this_obj[key]);

            return result;
        }
});
```

Comment: [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: It's just taking the key name string into result

Comment: Some problems... `result` is undefined and returning from the `forEach` callback does nothing

Comment: assume result and this_obj are defined

Comment: Object.keys is commonly used to transpose data types such as going from object to an array of objects.

https://codepen.io/evenstensberg/pen/MROqOq

Comment: is forEach the same as map()?

Comment: @Don no. I suggest you read the documentation ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to iterate, because the loop will, at the most, only push to `result` (which is presumably already defined) if a key named `string` is on the object, and will only push the value at the `string` key. So, here's a simpler way to write it:

```
if (this_obj.hasOwnProperty('string')) {
  result.push(this_obj.string);
}
```

If `string` may not be enumerable, then this won't be *exactly* the same as the `Object.keys` loop, because `Object.keys` only iterates over enumerable properties, so you may use an enumerable check if needed:

```
if (this_obj.propertyIsEnumerable('string')) {
  result.push(this_obj.string);
}
```

(`propertyIsEnumerable` returns `false` if the property is not directly on the object)

I suppose in the *very* odd case that `this_obj` also has a *custom* `hasOwnProperty` or `propertyIsEnumerable` key, you should `call` it instead:

```
if (Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(this_obj, 'string')) {
  result.push(this_obj.string);
}
```